# Any alternative to regex email validation?

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I have managed to write a regex which validates an email.

```
'/[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(@{1})[a-zA-Z]+(\.)(com){1}/'
```

I am finding it pretty difficult to frame complete regex for email validation.

The thing is, I think it would be better for me if there is an alternative to regex.

Can this validation be done efficiently using if/else statements (or other conditional statements)?

Is there a fool-proof alternative to regex?

Comment: You know that you can find a regex for validating emails in like 5 seconds by googling it right?

Comment: Did you see any of the other threads on SO on the topic? For example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript?rq=1. or even  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address?rq=1..

Comment: why use regex for validating email when php have built in function for that

Comment: @Arg0n
Yes.I know that.But I use codes in my program only when I understand it completely.
Its better to understand and do it in case I need to make some changes.Otherwise it would be like,I am just mugging up codes and pasting it.
I should be capable of using regex in other cases also.right?

Comment: I usually just use indexOf('@') for JS validation.

Comment: @Andrew
Can you tell me more about it?
I am a beginner.Please understand.I am not familiar with all the functions.Moreover,official php documentation makes it more confusing.

Comment: Just check for a `@` followed by a `.` and send a verification email if you care, unless you specifically know what your mail API will accept. The standard allows all kinds of crazy things in email addresses and domains.

Comment: @DanWhite
Will that prevent someone from using '/n<script>blahblah</script>' in the input box?
I mean,I found that people often use that to enter malicious scripts into the database.I am not sure though.It's the internet knowledge.

Comment: @JeremyBanks
What if someone enters some malicious codes if I don't check the string completely?

Comment: @MathewsMathai Javascript validation is a massive waste of time for all except cosmetic purposes, so no, it;'s not for that. You should fully validate on the backend.

Comment: Don't try and execute email addresses, and you'll be fine. That's an escaping problem, not a validation one.

Comment: @MathewsMathai not sure you asking on frontend side or backend side...anways, if using php, you can use `var_dump(filter_var('bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));`, read more on http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php ... its pretty straight forward

Comment: @MathewsMathai *All user-provided input must be encoded when output.* Always use something like `htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8');` before displaying a value. *That* is how your protect yourself from XSS. See [this article](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/06/preventing-xss-vulnerabilities-in-php-everything-you-need-know) for more information about that. You shouldn't need your email verification to worry about security.

Comment: I am not sure if filter_var (@Andrew's suggestion) correctly supports internationalized domain names.

Comment: @DanWhite
Is it necessary to go through the complete documentation before using a particular programming language?
Its a genuine doubt guys.

Comment: @JeremyBanks judging by his pattern, I dont think he is including international domain name...but its good to mention that

Comment: @Andrew
Is international pattern something different from the regular example@gmail.com?

Comment: @MathewsMathai http://unicode.org/faq/idn.html It will still have an `@` and a `.`, but it's not restricted to latin letters and numbers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help guys!
I am planning to check out all these suggestions and use the best that suits me and my level of understanding!

Comment: as different language might have different approaches; solution might varies. I am getting out of this comment block. peace out

Comment: using `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` is the way to do it with PHP, but it doesn't handle all formats. A regex that handle all email addresses is longer than one page and is not really a serious alternative in production. Keep in mind that even if an email has a valid format, it may not exists. So the problem stays the same: you need to use an email confirmation procedure (send an email with a link to confirm). In this perspective, you only need to use a basic check.

Comment: Yeah.That sounds logical.
Thanks @CasimiretHippolyte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5 has the input type email:

```
<input type="email" ...>
```

This is supported in all browsers except safari.

With PHP, you can validate an email with:

```
$email = 'myEmail@gmail.com';
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
    echo 'Email is considered to be valid';
}
```

[PHP Validation](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php)

Here is more about [JavaScript email validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)  with a regex.

Notes:

Thinking about how should the regex look like for an email validation is not so easy. Other smart guys have spent their time with it. Just copy and paste the regex from a serious source (with permission), link to it, and you are done.

Comment: Is HTML 'type=email' , a validation in itself?
HTML is just a markup language,right?
Is it capable of checking for validity?
I mean,will it show an error if I enter 'Helloworld' instead of a mail id?

Comment: Yes, it does! You can test it here: https://jsfiddle.net/zo4xk0jk/

Comment: If the answer hast helped, feel free to upvote!

Comment: Someone just downvoted my post.
And I am back to 14 reputations.Not capable to upvote.So sorry!

Comment: _"You can go through the three validations [...] Then it is very likely an email address!"_ - it also becomes increasingly likely that a valid email address was _rejected_. Try `"Look at all these spaces!"@example.com` on for size.

Comment: Thanks for your hint! I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a best and fool-proof alternative to regex?

Pseudocode:

```
if (strpos($text, '@') === FALSE)
    print("not an email for sure")
else
    sendConfirmationEmailToVerifyItExists()
```

[The best way to validate an email address is to send an email to it](http://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/). Anything else will cause you to reject valid email addresses, because the rules are so complex.

Comment: sendConfirmationEmailToVerifyItExists() 
This one is not an inbuit function.right?

Can you elaborate a bit on strpos()?

Comment: That just checks if the emall contains a @. False as a return value means not. Read the docs.

Comment: Is regex syntax same in js and php?

Comment: @MathewsMathai Why are you asking him? His answer isn't even using regex. If you have new separate questions then post them as new questions.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no, there is no better way to play with strings other than regular expressions unless you are using a library/package that provides out of the box functions to use. Their utility/importance is simply reflected by the fact that they are available in all languages in one capacity or the other.

Here is the long answer.

Your question implies that your problem is not limited to validating an email address but rather validating strings using regular expressions.

First off, for an alternative, you can surely break a string up and treat it any way you like. All modern languages have a comprehensive list of string functions that you can use. However, you should also know that it will not be worth the effort and will make your code look messy.

Ultimately, you will wonder is there an easier and better way to do this to which the answer will be regular expressions.

As for them being hard to learn, I have met software professionals who have 10+ years industry experience but still use Google for their regular expression needs so you are not alone in that regard.

The only way to get better at them is to keep learning and practicing but isn't that the case with every skill?

Comment: I got it.But the thing is I am learning it all by myself.

Comment: Is regex syntax same in all the languages?

Comment: @MathewsMathai As far as I know, 75% of it is same in all the languages. The remaining 25% are just minor differences.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, I use this function:

```
function validate_email($email)  
{  
    return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false ? false : true;  
}
```

Comment: what does it filter?
I mean does it check for the international standards too?

Comment: Good point. As far as I know, it is based on RFC 822, that means only ASCII characters.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!
I would have upvoted your answer.But someone recently downvoted me to 14 and now I am not capable of upvoting.
So sorry.